# TCP idle connection performance

Tags: performance, tcp, connection

How does the server and client keep the TCP connection open? Is it heavy on the system both cpu-wise and/or network-wise even if the connection is idle?

Comment: This question is very broad, it all depends on what system you are using, what webserver, etc.

Comment: a simple open connection in a java program, nothing else. Just an open connection.

Comment: One open connection is not much, if you have more, memory and CPU usage will go up, you should try it out yourself to see how bad it really is.

Comment: Any idea to how much say, 100 concurrent TCP connections would take up? Best estimated guess?

Comment: I've never tried it, so can't tell you. Sorry.

Comment: I found a source with good info, if you're interested. Down below.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good article about it http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionManagementandProblemHandlingtheConnec-3.htm

It explains that when a TCP connection is idle, nothing happens on the network and when they need to send data the connection simply opens again.

Some people think the use of "keepalive" messages is necessary to limit the number of idle connections open, and to ensure that no 'broken' connections are kept open.

Others think the keepalive messages are a waste of resources, And possible accidental server disconnection problems.